# How turning off animation of system operation android programmatically

Tags: android

To save energy of my mobile device my app should turn off animation of system operation android. How can I turn off animation of system operation android programmatically? Does there exist some broadcast receiver for listen this action?

I mean that if you want more performance in your android you can go settings ("Menu-Settings-Display-Animation-NO ANIMATIONS")... I want know how do this programmatically...

Comment: It would help if you would explain, clearly and precisely, what you think "animation of system operation android" is.

Comment: sorry my english.. I meant that if you want more performance in your android you can go settings ("Menu-Settings-Display-Animation-NO ANIMATIONS")... I want know how make this programmatically... Do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

While I seem to recall that there might have been this option in old versions of Android, this option does not appear in newer ones. For example, my Galaxy Nexus does not have this option.

With respect to controlling window animations programmatically, the only options for those that I see (e.g., `ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE`) are now in `Settings.Global` as of Android 4.2 and cannot be modified by ordinary SDK apps. You might be able to control them in earlier versions of Android, though it is unclear what settings directly translate into your Settings option.

Moreover, if you have evidence that changing these values will materially "save energy of [your] mobile device", please post it.

Comment: My app will be executed just in android 2.2 ... thks.